genisoimage --f error on ubuntu and mint
Can anyone help a beginner out? I'm trying to run genisoimage on a Windows 10 folder to create a bootable ISO file. Here's what I've done so far:
genisoimage -output "/home/yikes/Desktop/10/Win10_split.iso" \
-no-emul-boot \
-b boot/etfsboot.com \
-boot-load-seg 0 \
-boot-load-size 8 \
-eltorito-alt-boot \
-no-emul-boot \
-b efi/win_efi_boot.img \
-boot-load-size 1 \
-iso-level 4 \
-UDF \
/home/yikes/Desktop/win10work/

I've tried rearranging some of the commands and I've also tried omitting a few, but I still keep hitting the following stumbling block:

genisoimage: invalid option -- 'F'
Usage: genisoimage [options] -o file directory ...
Use genisoimage -help
to get a list of valid options.

I know the whole genisoimage issue has been raised a thousand times, but even after duckduckgoIng it I still can't find any results for:

genisoimage: invalid option -- 'F'

Please help a brother out!!!

First of all use -o intead of -output.

Mint is off topic on this Ubuntu only site.

I FINALLY figured it out;. Where is says -UDF i changed it to -udf (lowercase)
